# if $\phi$ is a characteristic function, then $|\phi|^2$ is also a characteristic function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, characteristic-functions

Show that if $\phi$ is a characteristic function of some random variable, then $|\phi|^2$ is also a characteristic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with characteristic function $\phi$ the $Ee^{it(X-Y)}=|Ee^{itX}|^{2}$  so the answer is YES.